# How do I section Biblatex footnotes by style?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I am using `\autocite{some citation key}` for my numerical referenced footnotes and
`\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}\footnote{some added text information}\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}` for the roman numeral footnotes.

Is there a way to separate them in the footnote section, so that the numerial footnote style is listed before the roman numeral footnote style?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `manyfoot` package to define new 'levels' of footnotes. Then you just need to tell `biblatex` to use the new footnote level and redefine the usual footnote level to permanently use Roman numerals.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-inote, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{BLX}

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd{\blx@mkbibfootnote}[2]{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\blx@warning{Nested notes}%
     \addspace\mkbibparens{#2}}
    {\unspace
     \ifnum\blx@notetype=\tw@
       \expandafter\@firstoftwo
     \else
       \expandafter\@secondoftwo
     \fi
       {\csuse{blx@theendnote#1}{\protecting{\blxmkbibnote{end}{#2}}}}
       {\csuse{footnote#1BLX}{\protecting{\blxmkbibnote{foot}{#2}}}}}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum\footnote{dolor}
sit\autocite{worman}
amet\autocite{sigfridsson}
consectur\footnote{sit}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: i dolor//ii sit////1 Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.//2 Nancy Worman. The Cast of Character. Style in Greek Literature. Austin: University of Texas Press, 2002.//3 Sigfridsson and Ryde, see n. 1.]

---

In a current version of LaTeX you can restart the citation footnotes in each chapter by adding

```
\counterwithin*{footnoteBLX}{chapter}
```

to the preamble. If you are using an older LaTeX version where that command is not yet in the kernel, it is probably easiest to use `\makeatletter\@addtoreset{footnoteBLX}{chapter}\makeatother`.

The space between the footnote types can be adjusted with

```
\setlength{\skip\footinsBLX}{5pt}
```

---

Och, I missed the bit about the citations coming before the Roman footnotes. I couldn't find a way around that that did not require defining a new footnote type for normal footnotes. But at least we can keep on using the original LaTeX footnotes for the citations, which makes the code shorter. For example like this

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-inote, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{ROMAN}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteROMAN}{\roman{footnoteROMAN}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum\footnoteROMAN{dolor}
sit\autocite{worman}
amet\autocite{sigfridsson}
consectur\footnoteROMAN{sit}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @moewe, it seems that I preferred having the roman numerals come before the numerical, so the first part of your answer was perfect, but, before I added your stuff, my numerical footnotes would reset every chapter. Is it possible to have that happen after doing the multiple footnote level stuff?

Comment: Also, do any of the parameters in that first answer you gave decrease the space between the two footnote sections?

Comment: @N1RAV11 See the edit, please.

Comment: Brilliant! Both edits solved the problems. I have the newer version of latex so the first code bit worked. Thanks!