# How can I use different counters for footcites and footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, footcite

I know this is probably a duplicate, but I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for.

I have a document with several footcites that are (by default) referred to with numbers. Now I need to add some footnotes, but if I just use `\footnote{Foo}` the footnote is numbered following the same counter of the footcites. That means people reading the document can't know what foot-thing the symbol is referring to without checking the bottom of the page, which I find rather annoying.

I'd like to use different counters for footcites and footnotes, possibly numbers for the first and letters for the latter. I would also like to have them written in different sections at the bottom of the page (i.e. footnotes and then footcites, disregarding what comes before in the source); this is not essential, though.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/552640/35864 help?